# What is the consistency SLA for Akka Clustering?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

How can I determine the maximum length of time cluster membership state will be inconsistent for across an Akka Cluster, assuming no further membership changes beyond the point we start measuring?

I realise this depends on several factors, so I'm looking for a way of calculating the worse-case given all the required variables.

Comment: I would recommend asking this question on the akka-user list.

Comment: I have just posted it, will provide a link once it gets approved :)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/0FzZIy06GKc